# Why is console.log(valu) returning an empty string?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: on the console it logs empty string]

**I want to save the value of an input and use it to create a customized message with the name of the person. when I console it I get an empty string**.

I was asked to add some more details to my post so I have added a prt sc image. Kindly see it.

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body');
let startContainer = document.createElement('div');
let fom = document.createElement('form');
body.prepend(startContainer);
startContainer.prepend(fom);
let playerName = document.createElement('input');
fom.prepend(playerName);
let btn = document.createElement('button');
fom.appendChild(btn);

//startContainer.appendChild(btn);
btn.textContent='enta'

function wlcomeM (val){
    return val + " you are welcome"
    
};

function player (playername, x, y){
    return playername.setAttribute(x, y);
    
}
//player(playerName, 'type', 'text');
player(startContainer, 'id', 'cv');
player(playerName, 'placeholder', 'enta ur name');
player(playerName, 'type', 'text');
player(playerName, 'id', 'name1');
player(playerName, 'name', 'plname');
player(fom, 'name', 'form');
player(btn, 'onclick', 'wlcomeM()');




let valu = document.forms['form']['plname'].value;

let tx = wlcomeM(valu);
console.log(tx)
console.log(valu)


//write a function that welcome player;






function welcomeM (player){
    return player + ' you are welcome';
};
let p  = welcomeM('Barthlo');
console.log(p)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<title>Start</title>
</head>
<body>




<script src='gameStart.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can basically listen for the button. When it is pressed then get the value and call your greeting function.

Answer (score 0):

As your input box is blank as the default so the variable 'valu' is blank.
When you pass it to a function 'welcomeM' and set it to 'tx', 'valu' is not updated as you only return a new string from 'welcomeM'. Hence it is showing blank

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You can archieve this by far more easily.
I would recommend using an eventlistener to listen when your button gets clicked.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){//do something});
```

Then when it's pressed get the value of your input field

```
let val = input.value;
```

Call your function with the value of the input field and greet the user

```
function(user)welcomeM{
    console.log("Welcome " + user);
}

// or better using template strings
function(user)welcomeM{
    console.log(`Welcome ${user}`);
}
```

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body');
let startContainer = document.createElement('div');
body.prepend(startContainer);
let playerName = document.createElement('input');
startContainer.prepend(playerName);
let btn = document.createElement('button');
startContainer.appendChild(btn);

//startContainer.appendChild(btn);
btn.textContent='enta'

//let valu = document.forms['form']['plname'].value;

//let tx = wlcomeM(valu);
//console.log(tx)
//console.log(valu)


//write a function that welcome player;


function welcomeM (player){
    console.log(  'you are welcome ' + player)
};


// here my edits

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
let val = playerName.value;
welcomeM(val);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<title>Start</title>
</head>
<body>




<script src='gameStart.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```